# GreenDao can't set up database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, orm, greendao

I'm using GreenDao for my Android project. But there is a little problem!
I can't start my application, because there is some failure on my database connection

The Error:

```
Could not find Class "...\DaoMaster" referenced form method "...\onCreate
```

I can't find a solution, some say, it depends on the "this" in my DevOpenHelper statement.
But all this solutions don't help.

Here is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

//db helper and dao
private SQLiteDatabase db;
private DaoMaster daoMaster;
private DaoSession daoSession;
private NoteDao noteDao;
private Cursor cursor;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //set up database
    DevOpenHelper helper = new DaoMaster.DevOpenHelper(this, "notes-db", null);
    db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    daoMaster = new DaoMaster(db);
    daoSession = daoMaster.newSession();
    noteDao = daoSession.getNoteDao();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I resolve the problem by changing the build path to force export the Android private libraries and put it on the top.

Answer (score 0):

Edit app/build.gradle to put greendao in the first.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.greenrobot:greendao:3.2.0'
}
```

I hope that will help you.